# Merge images together in canvas using JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm currently trying to add watermark to an image, and I'm using this script:

```
function mixImages(){
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj1 = new Image(); 
    var imageObj2 = new Image(); 
    var marginTop = 10; 
    var marginLeft = 10;
    imageObj1.src = "http://localhost:8080/sisop/storage/app/public/files/16522147787.png"
    imageObj1.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 328, 526);
        imageObj2.src = "http://localhost:8080/sisop/storage/app/public/files/165221397618.png";
        imageObj2.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, marginLeft, marginTop, 100, 100);
            var img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
  };
}
```

Which works fine if I'm only doing it with 1 canvas. But I'm trying to do this dynamically to every image that is loaded in my PHP code. so I'm trying to do this:

```
foreach($collection as $file){
    echo "
                        
         <div class='posts-cards'>
                            
             <canvas id='myCanvas$file->id' width='300' height='300'></canvas>

         </div>

         <script>

             var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas$file->id');
             var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
             var imageObj1 = new Image(); 
             var imageObj2 = new Image(); 
             var marginTop = 10; 
             var marginLeft = 10;
             imageObj1.src = 'http://localhost:8080/sisop/storage/app/public/files/16522147787.png'
             imageObj1.onload = function() {
                 ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 328, 526);
                 imageObj2.src = 'http://localhost:8080/sisop/storage/app/public/files/165221397618.png';
                  imageObj2.onload = function() {
                      ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, marginLeft, marginTop, 100, 100);
                      var img = c.toDataURL('image/png');
                  }
              };

         </script>
```

But for some reason, the result is this:
[image]

I have "display: flex; flex-flow: wrap; " in my css (it's supposed to be 2 rows of 4 items in each), so, for some reason, only  the 5th and 8th image are being generated.. And as you can see, only the last image has actually "merged" with the other image. I'm pretty stuck in here and don't quite understand what is going on here..

Comment: All the variables in your script block are in the global scope, so they will of course overwrite each other, when you output this script block multiple times ...

Comment: But how does it make sense to have 2 images generated ?

Comment: Ok, i just changed the name of the variables to have the file id in them, now it works!! Sorry about the question... thanks for your help!

Comment: What you rather _should_ change this to, is a _function_ that gets parameters passed to identify which elements it should work on.

Comment: Will do! i was just trying to make it work!!